# How to interpret a 95% CI: 1.00-1.00 with a p-value = 0.004

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, odds-ratio

I am performing a missing data analysis from a modified (the original data has been modified for the purposes of teaching) Randomised Control Trial.

The missing variable of interest is **"prior use of aspirin before randomisation"**.

There are eight other variables in the dataset. The key variable of interest for this post is **"systolic blood pressure"**.

Comparing those with missing data for systolic blood pressure with those not missing data for systolic blood pressure gives me the following mean systolic blood pressures:

- Not Missing (158.7)
- Missing (160.6)

Univariate logistic regression (previous aspirin as the outcome variable - Yes/No, systolic blood pressure as the exposure variable) gives me an OR = 1, a significant p-value=0.002, but a 95% CI: 1.00-1.00.

Similarly, multivariate regression gives me an OR = 1, p=0.004, but a 95% CI: 1.00-1.00.

**How should I interpret this?** Can I say that there is a statistically significant difference in the systolic blood pressure of those that are missing data for previous aspirin use (160.6) compared to those with data for previous aspirin use (158.7)?

If so, how should I understand the apparent oddity in the confidence interval? Is it simply because of the accuracy (number of significant figures) in the OR reporting?

Thanks

Comment: Try letting the software print out more digits or/and rescale the blood pressure to have greater units, +10 mmHg instead of 1 mmHg, say.

Comment: #COOLSerdash Yes, I would like to have done this, but all I have been given is the output from the R code. We are tasked with interpreting the missing data. We are being asked to "pretend" a colleague has got this output and does not know what to do with it. I do not have any of the original R code, so I can't actually manipulate anything. Is it conceivable that an OR could be statistically significant like this, given the scale is in 1mmHg? Thanks

Comment: I mean, if all calculations are correct, the $p$-value is 0.004 and the confidence interval will not include $0$.

Comment: @COOLSerdash Thank you. I got some clarity based on your suggestions, and further down the document, where they are actually performing the complete case analysis, the paper uses a scale of +10mmHg. Putting it all together, I can see how the original scale of 1mmHg would explain the apparent oddity. Thanks again.